# How to make a border between rows with length 2 columns?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with following rows:

```
<tr class = 'output' style='border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;'>
```

But I need border will have a length 2 columns (now it has a length 5 (all columns). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, you'd have to set the `border-bottom` on the `td`:

```
<tr class = 'output'>
  <td style='border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;'></td>
  <td style='border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;'></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Alternatively you could do this with CSS:

```
table tr.output td:nth-child(1), table tr.output td:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/awUTV/